# Display "program splash screen" using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, user-interface, zenity

I'm developing a program that is meant to be used in the computers of the company I work, all of them have a linux system based that we maintain. I would like to make this program more pretty by adding a screen when it starts, that contains some infos and the logo of the app, I was thinking more like a screen similar to the one libreoffice shows when you start it.

[image]

I tried using some of the image displays that we have on linux, like feh, imagemagick(display), but they are not what I'm looking for, even though the image will be displayed for only about 3 seconds, having the HUD that they offer, which have the option to delete the image, is not the ideal. I'm using zenity for the GUI in the rest of the script, but I don't see how I could still be using it for this functionality. In summary I need to display a splash image when I open my program, and it need to have no header no name, nothing, just the image like libreoffice. Has anyone tried this before? Thanks.

Comment: You want a graphical splash screen for a text application?

Comment: What's wrong with `timeout 3 feh -x foo.gif`

Comment: What Window Manager are you running?

Comment: @stark `timeout 3 feh -x foo.gif` don't run the gif actually

Comment: If you need to run an animation, please edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://github.com/step-/yad-lib/blob/master/usr/share/doc/yad-lib/index.md#keeping-yad-window-position-and-size) says:

> "`$1-window-xid` - Select the target `yad` window by its hexadecimal
> ID. If empty, it is replaced by the value of `$YAD_XID`, which `yad`
> automatically exports to children dialog windows."

`--uri-handler="$YAD_XID"` tells webkit (I'm assuming) that this `yad` instance is to handle URI's returned by this window.  Without it, the default browser will open.  The `--browser` & `--html` flags give `yad` the browser behavior. Setting the `--user-agent` can be required when you're loading an external site's `--uri`.

In the comment, `--uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000"` is `live-server` running on port 5000, which loads a [website I cloned for offline use](https://superuser.com/a/1786639/788170).

```
yad --window-icon="favicon.png" --title="JSON Editor" --geometry="1190x500" --center --uri-handler="$YAD_XID" --browser --html --uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000"
```

[image: Example yad]

---

[Here's an example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xsmJylACFDSFbtWrDPRwRWCUsG7GNCB2/view?usp=sharing) of `--splash`. Server use is not required, you can use: `--uri=index.html`.

Comment: thats a great solution, works well

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, the only way to include an image with zenity is in the first column of a tabular list using `--imagelist`. But this would be an icon-sized image, and all the other parts of the table, the frame, the buttons etc. would still have to be removed (if this is possible at all).

My suggestion would be to migrate to a similar tool that has image displaying capabilities, like [yad](https://github.com/v1cont/yad) for example. It can even act like a proper splashscreen using the `--splash` flag, and it would also offer a progress bar using the `--progress` flag, if needed.

```bash
yad --splash --timeout 3 --no-buttons --no-focus --image logo.png
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
zenity --text-info --timeout="3" --title="program" --width=800 --height="406"  --html --url="link to the gif or image" &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Cool. I have [zenity](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/zenity) 4.0.1 installed (including for dependencies: gtk 4.12.5 and libadwaita 1.4.2), but the options `--html` and `--url` aren't recognized. I also installed webkit2gtk 2.42.4, as suggested on zenity's page to have "HTML support", but I still don't get these options. Can you include what (and which versions) you have installed? Thanks.

Comment: My zenity version is 3.32.0, and I have two gtk versions, one is 3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1, and the other 2.24.32-4ubuntu4. About libadwaita, I don't know where to find it. I also tried to use the `--html` on yad, but it won't work.

Comment: `yad --window-icon="favicon.png" --title="Test" --geometry="1190x500" --center --uri-handler="$YAD_XID" --browser --html --user-agent="MIGHT_NEED_SET" --uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000"`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).